# Benchmarking concurrent connections capacity

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I know what the capacity is in terms of the number of sql user connections my hardware can support?

We know what the average number of connections is, and we know that there is a hard limit on enterprise (our version) of somewhere in the neighborhood of 37K.

However, we don't know how to determine or if there are any good rules of thumb for how many connections we can realistically support before we need to grow another server.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, all applications connecting to your database should use some form of connection pooling.  This will drastically cut down on the number of open connections to your database.

If this isn't being done, this should be a top priority.

In my experience, you'll start to suffer all types of issues when the number of connections to Sql Server is around 15,000, but this will of course vary on your hardware / OS.

One issue was that the pool of memory that was used to manage open connections was exhausted, causing new connection attempts to fail for this reason.

Another issue was that so many connections were being made to the server, the OS thought that it was being attacked with a denial of service attack, and had to make [registry tweaks in order to disable this protection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938202.aspx).

In summary, if the number of connections to your Sql Server is a concern, then you have an application / architectural problem that should be addressed.  Too many connections causes Sql Server to die in unusual and difficult to troubleshoot ways, and should be avoided altogether.

Comment: The situation you are describing is exactly what we are trying to prevent. We do not want to get ourselves into a situation where the connections get dropped due to a hardware resource limitation. As for pooling, we have been doing that for awhile. We are trying to find a way to calculate the 80% capacity so we can grow another server before problems arise.